# Video player overrides night light

Tags: display, gnome-shell

Can somebody please help me turn on on the [night light](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en) for videos on Ubuntu. [Night light](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en) works fine elsewhere but for some reason, it's not working on videos.

Comment: @K7AAY It's the inbuilt blue light filter feature in newer versions of GNOME.

Comment: Which video playing app do you use? Gnome video https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos , VLC http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ , mplayer http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html , or something else? Please click [edit] to add it to the original question. Please do not respond with Add Comment since new comments push old comments off the screen